# ¿Ayuda con mi gráfica de R, ordenar elementos?

Tags: r, ordenamiento

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
set.seed(2)
a<-sample(c(paste0("Id_",1:20)), size = 1000, replace = T)
b<-sample(c("preso","libre","proceso"), size = 1000, replace = T)

df<-data.frame(a,b)
```

Si realizo la tabla entre la columna a y b. obtengo lo siguiente:

```
resumen<-round(prop.table(table(df$a,df$b), 1)*100,2)
```

```
        libre preso  proceso
  Id_1  39.47 36.84   23.68
  Id_10 50.00 29.55   20.45
  Id_11 32.08 43.40   24.53
  Id_12 41.51 39.62   18.87
  Id_13 42.37 25.42   32.20
  Id_14 42.86 34.69   22.45
  Id_15 30.51 22.03   47.46
  Id_16 42.86 26.19   30.95
  Id_17 22.92 37.50   39.58
  Id_18 33.90 30.51   35.59
  Id_19 34.15 31.71   34.15
  Id_2  40.00 30.00   30.00
  Id_20 39.66 25.86   34.48
  Id_3  30.61 38.78   30.61
  Id_4  31.48 31.48   37.04
  Id_5  32.00 38.00   30.00
  Id_6  36.67 31.67   31.67
  Id_7  44.00 30.00   26.00
  Id_8  18.00 42.00   40.00
  Id_9  40.74 27.78   31.48
```

Si deseo realizar la gráfica sólo de los que están **libres** y deseo ordenarlo de forma decreciente uso la siguiente sintaxis:

```
resumen<-resumen[,1]

resumen<-sort(resumen, F)
```

Y obtengo la siguiente gráfica. Con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
resumen_g<-barplot(resumen, horiz = T, las=2, xlim = c(0,65))

text(resumen+3, resumen_g, format(resumen), cex = 0.8)
```

Aquí la gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero necesito agregar una etiqueta en donde se muestre en valores nominales los valores de ser libre entre el total de cada individuo.

Para realizar esto realizo el siguiente código

```
text_1<-addmargins(table(df$a,df$b),2)
```

EL resultado de esto es:

```
       libre preso proceso Sum
  Id_1     15    14       9  38
  Id_10    22    13       9  44
  Id_11    17    23      13  53
  Id_12    22    21      10  53
  Id_13    25    15      19  59
  Id_14    21    17      11  49
  Id_15    18    13      28  59
  Id_16    18    11      13  42
  Id_17    11    18      19  48
  Id_18    20    18      21  59
  Id_19    14    13      14  41
  Id_2     12     9       9  30
  Id_20    23    15      20  58
  Id_3     15    19      15  49
  Id_4     17    17      20  54
  Id_5     16    19      15  50
  Id_6     22    19      19  60
  Id_7     22    15      13  50
  Id_8      9    21      20  50
  Id_9     22    15      17  54
```

Es decir, deseo que la etiqueta del primer individuo sea libre entre la suma, por ejemplo para el primero 15/38 para el segundo 22/44 y así sucesivamente:

Para hacer esto realizo el siguiente sintaxis:

```
text_p<-text_1[,1]
text_s<-text_1[,4]
text_f<-paste(text_p, text_s, sep = "/")
```

Y ahora lo agrego a la imagen, con el siguiente código:

```
resumen_g<-barplot(resumen, horiz = T, las=2, xlim = c(0,65))

text(resumen+3, resumen_g, format(resumen), cex = 0.8)
text(resumen-5, resumen_g, format(text_f), cex = 0.8)
```

Lo que me resulta en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como se podrán dar cuenta ésta última etiqueta no ha estado ordenada. Es decir, **22/54** no es 50%.

No sé como ordenar esta etiqueta en función a mi orden anterior.

Alguna ayuda... Quizá algún comando que simplifique mi explicación.

**Muchas Gracias de antemano**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que has ordenado de diferente forma las etiquetas en la variable `text_f` y en la variable `resumen`. Código:

```
set.seed(2)
a<-sample(c(paste0("Id_",1:20)), size = 1000, replace = T)
b<-sample(c("preso","libre","proceso"), size = 1000, replace = T)

df<-data.frame(a,b)

resumen <- addmargins(table(df$a,df$b),2)

# Crear las etiquetas con las fracciones
text_f <- paste(resumen[,1], resumen[,4], sep = "/")
# Crear las etiquetas con los porcentajes
resumen <- round(prop.table(table(df$a,df$b), 1)*100,2)[,1]
# Ordenar primero las etiquetas
text_f <- text_f[order(resumen)]
# Ordenar los porcentajes
resumen<-resumen[order(resumen)]
# Crear gráficos
resumen_g<-barplot(resumen, horiz = T, las=2, xlim = c(0,65))
text(resumen+3, resumen_g, format(resumen), cex = 0.8)
text(resumen-5, resumen_g, format(text_f), cex = 0.8)
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: Muchas gracias!!